# Selective list deletions

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list:

```
lis = {{a,b,c},{d},{e,f},{g},{h,i,j}}
```

I would like to remove each element that consists of only one subelement from the list to get:

```
res = {{a,b,c},{e,f},{h,i,j}}
```

This seems to be for SequenceReplace, but I'm having trouble with structuring the command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Cases[lis, Except[{_}]]` should be good.

OR

```
Select[lis, Length[#] > 1 &]

Pick[lis, Length[#] > 1 & /@ lis]

DeleteCases[lis, {_}]

lis /. {_} -> Nothing
```

**EDIT** a few more

```
Select[lis, Rest[#] != {} &]

Select[lis, Most[#] != {} &]

Select[lis, Last@TakeDrop[#, 1] != {} &]
```

Comment: `Cases`, `DeleteCases`, and `Select` can all be used here. But as a purely aesthetic point, I would prefer to use either `Cases` or `Select` so that I can know with certainty the structure of the elements that I have retained in the next step. With `DeleteCases`, I would need to use the structure up to that point, and the pattern I have chosen to delete, in order to come to a conclusion about the structure of the result.

Answer (score 9):

```
Cases[{_, __}] @ lis
```

> ```
> {{a, b, c}, {e, f}, {h, i, j}}
> ```

Answer (score 4):

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d}, {e, f}, {g}, {h, i, j}};
```

Using `SequenceSplit` (new in 11.3)

```
Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {{_}}]
```

{{a, b, c}, {e, f}, {h, i, j}}

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {{a, b, c}, {d}, {e, f}, {g}, {h, i, j}};
```

---

Using `GroupBy`:

```
GroupBy[list, Length@# > 1 &][True]

(*{{a, b, c}, {e, f}, {h, i, j}}*)
```

Or using `Replace` at level `1`:

```
Replace[list, s : {_} :> Nothing, {1}]

(*{{a, b, c}, {e, f}, {h, i, j}}*)
```

Comment: I always forget these nice `GroupBy` solutions :)

Comment: Thanks, @eldo ;)